# Play Framework - CRUD - ImageUpload

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using play 1.2.5 with the CRUD module and now try to upload images for an entity. It has the
property

public Blob image;

It works via the tutorial on
"[Play framework CRUD file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418520/play-framework-crud-file-upload/14875762#14875762)"
, but is it somehow possible to save the image not as a File with a hashtag name and without extension, but instead as the original file name and extension, just a copy? For example if I upload a "test.jpg" I want play to save a "test.jpg" in my app and the path to this file in the database-table!